# Create dynamic tabs when use custom section

Tags: angularjs, umbraco

When create a custom section, you can add it in umbraco via `Dashboard.config` file like:

```
<section alias="sectionName">
      <areas>
         <area>mySection</area>
      </areas>
      <tab caption="Main">
         <control>
            /App_Plugins/.../view.html
         </control>
      </tab>
</section>
```

Instead of `Main`, how to create dynamically the tabs ?

I have an angularjs controller and I get some data from server.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help you get on the way. It's hardly a complete answer, but it should help.

### Child pages

I don't believe you have control over the tabs in the dashboard, instead they have to be hard coded into the `Dashboard.config`. This is because Umbraco controls the header on this page. This allows different packages to add sections to each the same dashboard without any hacking.

However, you can dynamically control the tabs on a child page, such as at `/umbraco/#/mySection/myTree/edit-1?create`. On child pages, you can create and edit the header.

**view.html**

```
<div ng-controller="myNamespace.myController">
    <umb-panel>
        <umb-header tabs="content.tabs">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                View name
            </div>
        </umb-header>
        <umb-tab-view>
            <umb-tab id="tab1" rel="myTab1">
                Tab 1 content
            </umb-tab>
            <umb-tab id="tab1" rel="myTab2">
                Tab 2 content
            </umb-tab>
        </umb-tab-view>
    </umb-panel>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('umbraco').controller('myNamespace.myController',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.content = {
            tabs: [
                { id: 1, label: "myTab1" },
                { id: 2, label: "myTab2" }
            ]
        };
    });
```

### In your view (but not the header)

If you must create tabs on your dashboard page, you can put tabs into the main content area (but not at the top in the header).

**view.html**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        Tab 1 content
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        Tab 2 content
    </div>
</div>
```

You can then control these tabs in your Angular with `ng-repeat` (etc).